# sqlite update each row of a column with the result of a select (again)

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I need to add a column to a table then fill it with computed values from a select (from the orignal table itself) like this

```
create table yo (ad integer primary key, pa integer, pd integer);
insert into yo values
  (1,1,1),(2,1,3),(3,1,4),(4,3,5),(5,4,2),(6,3,8),(7,1,9),(8,6,7),(9,3,6);
.header on
.mode column yo;
select * from yo;
ad          pa          pd
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           1
2           1           3
3           1           4
4           3           5
5           4           2
6           3           8
7           1           9
8           6           7
9           3           6
```

The 'ad' col is a kinda address, the 'pa' col is a parent address, the 'pd' col is a kinda ID or value for that row. 
I'd like to add a col named 'pp' that would be a 'parent ID' that would be computed like this

```
select yo2.pd from yo yo1 join yo yo2 on yo2.ad=yo1.pa;
pd
----------
1
1
1
4
5
4
1
8
4
```

So I'd like to setup 'pp' whit this output I tried this but obviously I must miss somethings

```
alter table yo add column pp integer;
update yo set pp =
  (select yo2.pd as pp from yo yo1 join yo yo2 on yo2.ad=yo1.pa);

ad    pa   pd   pp
----  ---  ---  ---- 
1     1    1    1
2     1    3    1
3     1    4    1
4     3    5    1
5     4    2    1
6     3    8    1
7     1    9    1
8     6    7    1
9     3    6    1
```

Does what I want to achieve is doable, I so othre link on similar proble that I don't understand the answers, and I found also tiny case like this

```
create table t1 (a int, b int);
insert into t1 values (1,0),(2,0);
create table t2 (a int, c int);
insert into t2 values (1,101),(2,102);
update t1 set b = (select c from t2 where t2.a = t1.a) where t1.b = 0;
```

This one do update correctly so why my select differ from this later one?
Thanx for any advise
Phi

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve what I want to do using a temp table like this

```
create temp table ziv as
  select yo1.ad,yo2.pd as pp from yo yo1 join yo yo2 on yo2.ad=yo1.pa
update yo set pp=(select temp.ziv.pp from temp.ziv where temp.ziv.ad=yo.ad)
select * from yo
ad  pa   pd  pp
--- ---  --- ---
1   1    1   1
2   1    3   1
3   1    4   1
4   3    5   4
5   4    2   5
6   3    8   4
7   1    9   1
8   6    7   8
9   3    6   4
```

Now I wonder will this can be done with only 1 update (no temp table)
Thanx in advance
Cheers
Phi

Answer (score 0):

The subquery must refer to the current row in the outer UPDATE query, i.e., to some value in `yo`'s current row.

This is not immediately possible with JOIN; you have to convert the join condition into a WHERE clause first:

```
...(select yo2.pd as pp from yo yo1, yo yo2 where yo2.ad=yo1.pa)
```

and then omit the `yo` that refers to the outer query from the subquery (the table in the UPDATE cannot be renamed):

```
update yo set pp =
   (select yo2.pd as pp from yo yo2 where yo2.ad=yo.pa);
```

Comment: Thanx CL for your reply, dunno why I added a reply that goes before yours, I got hard time to understand the stackoverflow logic of chronology of replies.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx CL for your reply
I didn't saw your reply in time, probably because I didn't refresh my page, so I pursued in the logic of my last answer, and I came up with the final query that seems to do the job with no intermediate table.

```
update yo set pp=(select pp from
(select yo1.ad as ad1,yo2.pd as pp from yo yo1 join yo yo2 on
   yo2.ad=yo1.pa)
   where ad1=yo.ad);
```